# what is more correct: "car future" or "future of cars"

Tags: word-usage

What is more correct?

> car future, medicine future, mail future

OR

> future of cars, future of medicine, future of mail.

Also: **car of future** or **car of the future**?

Comment: I wonder why -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not referring to *types* of futures, but to the future *in respect to* each of those things, you would use **of**:

> The future of cars
>
> The future of medicine
>
> The future of mail

The article is needed, **Cars of *the* future.** or **The car of *the* future**.

**Cars of the future**   (Cars, *in general*, in the future)

**The car of the future** (The *prototypical* car of the future)

You can also use **future** as an adjective:

> Future cars
>
> Future medicine
>
> Future mail

or construct a prepositional phrase:

> In the future, cars will...
>
> In the future, medicine will...
>
> In the future, mail will ...

When a noun is placed before another noun, it specifies a *type* or kind:

mail bag  (This kind of bag is used to carry mail)

feed bag  (This kind of bag is placed over a horse's head; it might contain oats, the horse's "feed")

> Paint can   (the sort of can which holds paint)
>
> Soda can    (the sort of can which is used to hold soft drinks)
>
> Trash can   (the sort of can which is used to hold household waste)

Comment: Feasibly your point *The article is needed, **The cars of the future***, I wonder if that might be misunderstood to apply to the ***first*** article in the example. Which of course ***isn't*** idiomatically required - as shown by, for example, ***Cars of the future probably won't have steering wheels***. But for contexts like that I vastly prefer your "prepositional phrase" construction anyway: ***In the future cars probably won't have steering wheels***.

Comment: The potential for confusion remedied just now.

Comment: ok, thank you! I like "future cars". This is most simple and neutral. But I dont understand why is the article so important in "the future of cars"? why not just "future of cars"?

Comment: Articles are a lot of trouble for learners of English whose native language doesn't have them. Articles serve to guide and orient the listener. You need to learn how to use them. That's just how it is.

Comment: @user79871: You should be cautious in making judgments like "Future cars *is the most simple and neutral*". The pattern does not express as clearly as **of the future** does, that you're referring to a future on the far side of  technological leaps.  Collocations tend to correlate with contexts, and **of the future** is the pattern most often used to refer to the future on the far side of huge technological advances.  **Future cars** could refer to next year's models.  *Future cars will have our six-speed automatic dual-clutch transmission.*

Comment: Tᴚoɯɐuo, well, now I understand. It's something like "coming cars"? Then it's not for me. I'll use "of the future" variant. Thank you!

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, as to the articles in "the car of the future". Why for example in the metro underground is it ok to drop the article in "do not lean on door"?

Comment: @user79871: Signage seeks brevity.  Similar to headlines.  Also, the sign is posted on or near the door, and so there's a visual replacement for the function served by the article.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, ok, then can I for a headline of a poster to write just "future of cars". And below write details of my vision of the future of the cars :)

Comment: **The Future of Cars** would be more idiomatic, even for a poster heading.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples of the form "car future" are not idiomatic.

"The future of cars" is an elipsis that is slightly ambiguous without additional context. It may mean "the future importance of cars," "the future function of cars," or "the future design of cars" or even something else. Notice that "future" is an adjective, but the noun being modified is not specified. When that kind of ellipsis is used in practice, the context will usually make quite clear what noun is intended.

"The car of the future" serves to introduce a predicted description of how cars will work in the future.